# React Native MQTT.js does not work on Android 9+

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, mqtt

I am building an Android app using **React Native 0.61** (CLI)
and use common MQTT.js packages here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt **(v.3.0.0)**

This is my **build.gradle**

```
buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 25
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
```

I use **WebSocket** protocol to connect to my own mqtt broker.

In debug mode, everything works perfectly on any phone. But weird that when I release APK by command 
 (*gradlew assembleRelease* (signed)), it can not connect to the broker on Android 9+ (both emulator) (Android 8 work well)

It seems there was a problem when compiling to native code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it may because the HTTP is default is disallowed since Andoird 9.you can add the following at the AndroidMainfest.xml.

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

you can also use a config XML. for that you can see this [blog](https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6)

Comment: I found this very very late. Already lost my 1.5 hr try adjusting my ssl config. Thank you, this works perfectly.

Comment: @tnchalise I am great it helps you, you can give it a vote to make more people can see it.