# How to display JPEG images for url starts with `http://` using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

The following code works to display PNG images but it doesn't work for the JPG images

```
GlideApp.with(playerBinding.ivLogoHomeTeam.context)
        .load("https://JPN-CR1@2x.png")
        .into(playerBinding.ivLogoHomeTeam)
```

XML:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_item_team_logo"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_item_team_logo"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/unit_dp_10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/unit_dp_10"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/unit_dp_10"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/unit_dp_10"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```

EDIT: JPEG images are working for HTTPS images, while the HTTP images are not working. How do we dislpay the HTTP images?

Comment: as I know, it supports it, can you show the imageView XML code?

Comment: @Lenoarod XML added. I tried manually adding jpg URL, still, it doesn't show up

Comment: can you share URL of that jpg image?

Comment: @johnrao07, are the URL of the jpg image is https or Http?

Comment: @Lenoarod PNG images are HTTPS and JPG are HTTP

Comment: Okay, JPG images are working with HTTPS. How do we display HTTP images?

Comment: @javadroid it's an issue with HTTP and HTTPS images. updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the `Http` permission problem. you should add the following for http request.

```
<application
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

/>
```

for detail, you can see my this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59112799/5705408).

but I also give how to find the error in Glide. firstly, you can use the [Gilde debug option](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/debugging.html) to find the info to solve the problem.

If you have access to the device, run this command `adb shell setprop log.tag.Glide DEBUG`, it will log both successful and failed requests and differing levels of detail depending on the log level. you can call `setLogLevel(int)` to set the level.

you can also  use the listener to find the exception error.

```
Glide.with(fragment)
   .load(url)
   .listener(new RequestListener() {
       @Override
       boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model,    
         Log.e(TAG, "Load failed", e);
         return false; // Allow calling onLoadFailed on the Target.
       }

       @Override
       boolean onResourceReady(R resource, Object model, Target<R> target,
           DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
         // Log successes here or use DataSource to keep track of cache hits and misses.
         return false;
       }
    })
    .into(imageView);
```